# C# Selenium: GetXpathCount shows 0

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, selenium

The following is a code snippet from the website I'm testing:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td width="2%" valign="top" align="center"> 
<td width="48%" valign="top" align="left"> 
<font class="wlCategoryLinkBold" size="2"> 
<a target="SearchFrame" href="http://wlAtlas.aspx?cmd=display=Administrative&wlTarget=wlReturnURL=PDocs.aspx">Administrative</a>
```

The code I have:

```
 public List<string> Search(ISelenium Sel) 
{ 
   Sel.Click(//*[@id="Search_Tab_Search"]); 
   List<string> topics = new List<string>(); 
   int se = (int) Sel.GetXpathCount("//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a"); 
   for (int i = 1; i <= se; i++) 
   { 
       if (Sel.IsElementPresent("//font[@class='wlcategoryLinkBold']/a[" + i + "]")) 
            { 
                 string value = Sel.GetText("//font[@class='wlcategoryLinkBold']/a[" + i + "]"); 
                 topics.Add(value); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest will be to use `selenium.getTable("table_name".colnumber.rownumber)`